# How do I use AngularJS to accept user input through a form and then use $http to post that data to a backend?

Tags: angularjs, http, ionic-framework

I want to package that data from the user input form into JSON and post it to a remote server. Could anybody either show me an example or direct me to a tutorial that shows how to do this?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials already that describe this process in quite a bit of detail, including the official documentation.  Have you made an attempt and run into some sort of issue?  As written, this is a request for tutorials or off site resources, which is off topic for this site due to the amount of spam these types of questions generate.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not why SO is for, but to help you i'll put a link here:

http://tutsnare.com/post-form-data-using-angularjs/

You can use Google next time.